# Content Type Issue while migrating from SP 2007 to SP 2010

Tags: content-type

I have migrated a content Database from SP 2007 to 2010. When i check the list settings, i can see that it has been associated with a content type . But when i check it in the site content type gallery , i cannot see it. What could be the problem ??

I have to associate this content type with my Content query web part. So the web part is also not working bcoz of this.

How can i resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance ,
Nikhil Kak

Comment: i am also facing the same problem... please can someone help !!

Answer (score 1):

Content Types have introduced with the `Inherit` attribute which is desirable in cases if you want a specific Content Type to inherit from a parent Content Type. Make sure to include this attribute and provision the Content Types again.

[Here is the more information](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/05/02/custom-content-types-and-inherits-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The destination 2010 farm needs to have the same custom features/solutions (WSPs and assemblies) must installed before running the Content DB upgrade.